# Transfer of control in Observer pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I am trying to implement observer pattern for my project. The `LeaveFields` class extends `Observable` and `LeaveGenerator` implements `Observer`.

```
private class LeaveFields extends Observable {

    private User user;
    private Date date;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(user);
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(date);
    }
}

private class LeaveGenerator implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object object) {
        if (object instanceof User) {
            System.out.println("==============User============");
        } else if (object instanceof Date) {
            System.out.println("==============Date============");               
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing is that, during the execution, any changes to the user or date will force `LeaveGenerator` to do some work. The changes to date is made by some code snippet like: `leaveFields.setDate(date);`. I am trying to understand the process of transferring control for any changes made. So far I found after executing `leaveFields.setDate(date);` that is doing some change, control shifted to the `update` method of observer.

```
//some code
leaveFields.setDate(date);
// code segments following this line wait until the update method of observer returns.
```

After `update` method finish its task the control returns. The current execution pauses temporarily while `update` is working.

Am I right and this is my question? At first I thought that the `update` is made in different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're using `java.util.Observable`.

Yes the single thread of execution will enter `notifyObservers` and callback to each registered `Observer`.  If you want to asynchronously notify the observers (so the call to `notifyObservers()` does not block until each has been called back) you will need to code explicitly for that.  As a reference here is the relevant source from `java.util.Observable`:

```
 private boolean changed = false;
 private Vector obs = new Vector();

 public void notifyObservers() {notifyObservers(null);}

  public void notifyObservers(Object paramObject){
    Object[] arrayOfObject;
    synchronized (this){
      if (!(this.changed))
        return;
      arrayOfObject = this.obs.toArray();
      clearChanged();
    }
    for (int i = arrayOfObject.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      ((Observer)arrayOfObject[i]).update(this, paramObject);
  }
```

Comment: thanks. Yes I am using `java.util.Observable`. No I need synchronous single threaded execution as this is suitable.